# How to use CSS&HTML to create a style like this Volume Ctrl bar?

Tags: html, css

Volume Ctrl bar

[image]

I can click on this little button and slide.

Comment: Where's the code you have made.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input:range`

`<input type='range' value='46'>`

also see sliders at CodePen by Ana Tudor
http://codepen.io/search/pens?q=slider&limit=thebabydino

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.
HTML-

```
<audio controls>
<source src="http://live96.917xfm.de/;stream" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
<div class="volume" title="Set volume">
```

CSS-

```
/* VOLUME BAR CSS */

/* volume bar */
 .volume {
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
width:100%;
height:20px;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:10px;
background-color:#000;
}
.volumeBar {
display:block;
height:20px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#888;
z-index:10;
width: 90%;
}
.volume3 {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 50px 100px;
border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
line-height: 0px;
_border-color: #000000 #000000 #007bff #000000;
_filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

JS-

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];


$('.muted').click(function () {
audio.muted = !audio.muted;
return false;
});

//VOLUME BAR
//volume bar event
var volumeDrag = false;
$('.volume').on('mousedown', function (e) {
volumeDrag = true;
audio.muted = false;
$('.sound').removeClass('muted');
updateVolume(e.pageX);
});
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
if (volumeDrag) {
    volumeDrag = false;
    updateVolume(e.pageX);
}
});
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
if (volumeDrag) {
    updateVolume(e.pageX);
}
});
var updateVolume = function (x, vol) {
var volume = $('.volume');
var percentage;
//if only volume have specificed
//then direct update volume
if (vol) {
    percentage = vol * 100;
} else {
    var position = x - volume.offset().left;
    percentage = 100 * position / volume.width();
}

if (percentage > 100) {
    percentage = 100;
}
if (percentage < 0) {
    percentage = 0;
}

//update volume bar and video volume
$('.volumeBar').css('width', percentage + '%');
audio.volume = percentage / 100;

//change sound icon based on volume
if (audio.volume == 0) {
    $('.sound').removeClass('sound2').addClass('muted');
} else if (audio.volume > 0.5) {
    $('.sound').removeClass('muted').addClass('sound2');
} else {
    $('.sound').removeClass('muted').removeClass('sound2');
}

};
```

This guy already has a working fiddle here[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/r44bzmc1/)